# JS error dialog box pop up

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, debugging, dialog

I am currently working on a wordpress site, and i am receiving a dialog box popup error everytime i load the site.

The error reads

```
The page at mydomain.com says: Ready!
```

Followed by 2 more identical pop ups and the option to prevent this page from creating additional dialogs

I tried wp debug. Running in debug and 2 errors appear:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Have code that you can post?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the source of the error.

I am using a countdown timer embedded on homepage and the timer had run out, and it was causing the issue.